# arrayFilters no funciona con pymongo pero si en la consola de MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Tengo este código en Python

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db       = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)['myDB']['myCol']
params   = { "model": "ILX ACURA" }
asset    = { "newAsset": ["Foo", "Bar", "Poo"] }
document = { "$push": { "models.$[mod].years": asset } }
filters  = { "arrayFilters" : [ { "mod.model": params['model'] } ] }
updated  = db.update( {}, document, False, False, None, filters )

if updated.matched_count > 0:
    print 'DONE!'
```

Cuando corro el script me aparece este error

> WriteError: No array filter found for identifier 'mod' in path
>   models.$[mod].years

Estuve peleando con Python mucho tiempo y lo intenté mejor en la consola de MongoDB

```
db.myCol.updateOne({}, { $push: { "models.$[mod].years": { "newAsset": ["Foo", "Bar","Poo"] } } }, { arrayFilters: [ { "mod.model": "ILX ACURA" } ] } )
```

Sorpresa!

> { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }

Que estará pasando?

Utilizo
python 2.7 
pymongo 3.8
mongoDB 4.0

Comment: si recibe un arrayFilters probablemente no tienes que agregarlo , por lo tanto el filtro deberia quedar asi : `filter = [ { "mod.model": params['model'] } ]` segun el [codigo fuente](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py#L793) parece ser que se agrega la palabra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como bien indica @JackNavaRow en su oportuno comentario, los filtros que aplicas deben ser pasados en una lista y no en un documento como lo tienes, sin embargo ese no es el único problema.

Según la documentación de `PyMongo` el método [`update`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) [está obsoleto (*deprecated*)](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py#L3195), y se sugiere usar uno de los métodos: [`replace_one`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one), [`update_one`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) o [`update_many`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many).

Usaremos `update_one` y podrás realizar la tarea, además te sugiero que siempre que intentes realizar operaciones sobre base de datos uses bloques `try except`

Tu código podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db       = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)['myDB']['myCol']
params   = { "model": "ILX ACURA" }
asset    = { "newAsset": ["Foo", "Bar", "Poo"] }
# llamamos update al documento que representa la actualización, así no hay confusión
# con el documento que se está actualizando
update = { "$push": { "models.$[mod].years": asset } }
# filters es una lista, no un documento, cada elemento de la lista define un filtro
filters  = [ { "mod.model": params['model'] } ]

#usamos un bloque try except
try:
    updated  = db.update_one( {}, update, False, False, None, filters )
    if updated.matched_count > 0:
        print 'DONE!'
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

Con esto debería funcionar lo que intentas realizar (para 1 documento).

**Edición**

Dado que al parecer tu intención es actualizar varios documentos, debes usar `update_many`.

Tu código cambia, ya que el orden de los argumentos pasados al método es diferente. Puedes consultar la [documentación](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many).

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db       = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)['myDB']['myCol']
params   = { "model": "ILX ACURA" }
asset    = { "newAsset": ["Foo", "Bar", "Poo"] }
# llamamos update al documento que representa la actualización, así no hay confusión
# con el documento que se está actualizando
update = { "$push": { "models.$[mod].years": asset } }
# filters es una lista, no un documento, cada elemento de la lista define un filtro
filters  = [ { "mod.model": params['model'] } ]

#usamos un bloque try except
try:
    # usamos update_many
    updated  = db.update_many( {}, update, False, filters )
    if updated.matched_count > 0:
        #si deseamos ver la cantidad de documentos afectados:
        print updated.matched_count
        print 'DONE!'
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

Espero que esto sea lo que estabas buscando.

Comment: @JackNavaRow El obsoleto es `update` (era el que usaba el OP en su pregunta). Le sugiero usar `update_one`, o `update_many`, dependiendo si quiere modificar 1 documento o muchos.